# how to read UDP buffer size on windows 10?

Tags: networking, udp, sockets

I have a server application that will receive more than 200 udp packet concurrently (strings of max 64 bytes), for testing and performance purpose I want to check the UDP buffer in my server to check if overflow the limit.
Is there a way to get this? Is it good to perform the buffer size check, when server receiving packet?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but the exact syntax depends on the programming language and the API provided. For example, in Python, we can get that by:

```python
import socket

# Create a UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
print('RCVBUF={}'.format(sock.getsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF)))
```

For your second question, yes it is generally a good idea to check if the buffer size is enough. On my Windows 10, the above code shows the default buffer size is 64 KiB, which seems big enough for your examples.